# webapi not recognize json list

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api2

I've got a list of objects in JSON that isn't recognized by a WebApi2 controller

The JSON list is the following:

```
{
 "FirstObjectType": [{"Name": "the_name"}], 
 "SecondObjectType": [{"Label": "01_obj"}, {"Label": "02_obj"}]
}
```

The Model class is:

```
public class CompositeObject
{
    [JsonProperty("FirstObjectType")]
    public List<FirstObject> fo { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("SecondObjectType")]
    public List<SecondObject> so { get; set; }
}
```

The controller is:

```
public IHttpActionResult PostList([FromBody] CompositeObject jsonList)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    List<FirstObject> fo_list = jsonList.fo;

    foreach (var item in fo_list)
    {
        db.FirstObject.Add(item);
        db.SaveChanges();
     }

     return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```

When I submit the Post action, the controller recognize both lists in CompositeObject jsonList as Null

Comment: Your JSON is incorrect here

Comment: @MegaTron my fault: copy/paste error!

Comment: You need to show the structure of  `FirstObject` and `SecondObject` as well.

Comment: see my updated answer below!

Comment: @Cyr: It would be helpful if you can add code to show how you are posting json data to controller.

Comment: @PankajKapare I'm using a Python client

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem in your model, where names are not being matched. You have to update model as:

```
public class FirstObjectType
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class SecondObjectType
{
    public string Label { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<FirstObjectType> FirstObjectType { get; set; }
    public List<SecondObjectType> SecondObjectType { get; set; }
}
```

I have assumed that `FirstObjectType` contains string with name `Name` and `SecondObjectType` contains string with name `Label`. Make sure to use same names for properties of `FirstObjectType` and `SecondObjectType` class as in JSON string.

Comment: You're making an assumption.  The OP hasn't shown the actual model classes.

Comment: added assumption. Thanks @DavidL for suggestion!

Comment: I take my Json and your Model but it doesn't work! Still a Null value...

Comment: @Cyr can you please post your model and how are you consuming this api?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was in the client code because I missed to set the Content-type as `application/json` in the header section.
In this way the WebApi server doesn't recognize in the right way the JSON object (I think that the server look for a x-www-form-urlencoded type)

So, the code above is right, but I have found another solution

In the WebApi controller:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

public IHttpActionResult PostList([FromBody] JObject ReceivedObjectsList)
{           
    var receivedLists = ReceivedObjectsList.Properties();

    List<FirstObject> fo = ReceivedObjectsList["FirstObjectType"].ToObject<List<FirstObject>>();
    List<SecondObject> so = ReceivedObjectsList["SecondObjectType"].ToObject<List<SecondObject>>();

    ...
}
```